# Need help with this question on circles. Please help asap.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

One circle has a radius of $5$ and its center at $(0,5)$. A second circle has a radius of $12$ and its center at $(12,0)$. What is the length of a radius of a third circle, which passes through the center of the second circle and both the points of intersection of first two circles.

I have solved this question using the equation for circles but it turns out that there is an easier method to solve this question. Our teacher said that all that is required to solve this is basic $10$-th grade maths. Can anyone tell me how to solve this using $10$-th grade math?

Comment: "please help asap" is very imperative...

Comment: So the homework is due tomorrow?

Comment: FYI, "please help ASAP" will get you downvotes here. +1 from me, though, because you told us about what you'd tried and put your question in the appropriate context of wanting a more "low-tech" solution. Welcome!

Comment: Try using the distance formula and drawing a picture on graph paper or in desmos.com

Comment: Do your homework yourself!

Comment: How was this closed as off-topic? Shameful. OP gave clear context and described their attempt.

Comment: To @KaranSingh (and OP), there is NOT a rule against asking homework questions here. It has come up repeatedly in meta, and that's always the decision. What we DO ask is that posters put their homework in context and describe their attempt. Which is what OP did!

Comment: I'm sorry If I've caused any trouble. I'm new to this community. Really very sorry.... Will not repeat this :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $A(0,5)$, $B(12,0)$ and two given circles intersect in the origin $O$ and in the point $C$.

Thus, the needed circle passes trough $A$, $B$, $C$ and $O$,

which is a circle with diameter $AB$ and since
$$AB=\sqrt{12^2+5^2}=13,$$ we got the answer: $$\frac{13}{2}.$$

Take the circle with diameter $AB$.

Since $\measuredangle AOB=90^{\circ}$ and $\Delta AOB\cong \Delta ACB$,

we see that this circle passes trough $A$, $B$, $C$ and $O$ and from here he passes trough $O$, $C$ and $B$.

Comment: You should add that to your answer, it's not obvious.

Comment: it is not given that the needed circle passes through A

Comment: @Vikram It's not given, but I proved it. See please my explanation.